# MATLAB, turning numbers off on plot

Tags: matlab

I'm pretty familiar with all of the axis properties for a matlab plot, but I can't seem to find any of them that actually effect displaying the numbers or not. I have a plot where numbers are pretty meaningless, they're only there to get a good visual representation of what I'm working on. So, it would be better if I could just have the numbers gone compeltely. Is there a way to do this? Thanks. (No not the tick marks or any of that, the actualy NUMBERS! =))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the tick marks you're after but the tick labels. Just set them to empty lists:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel', [], 'YTickLabel', [])
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect =), also if anyone is interested, I found that set(gca,'XTick',[]); turns off tick marks and the numbers if you just want your image